# Wordpress configuration : can’t write the wp-config.php file

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have install WordPress in my AWS Amazon linux machine(EC2).
Also i am able to connect to SQL Database instance use EC2 instance.

Now i am trying to configure WordPress using browser.I have taken the IP of Ec2 instance and put on browser.I got the wordPress Admin page and i have clicked on Lets Go.

After that i got the page which ask DatabseName,username,password,databse host and table prefix.I have provided these details and when clicked on Submit,got below error.

"Sorry, but I can’t write the wp-config.php file.
You can create the wp-config.php file manually and paste the following text into it."

What i am missing here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get access to wp-config.php file and add DB Name, User, Password directly if possible.

**OR**

Check File permission of wp-config.php it should be 644. or Write permission should be given to it.